# I need to add space between Price and "Rs"

Tags: magento2, price

I try to find the phtml file to add space between price and currency "Rs".

But haven't found in final_price.phtml.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it from backend
Click on `Stores > Currency > Currency Symbols`
Unchecked `use standard` and add `space` after the symbol of currency.

After run `php bin/magento cache:flush` or refresh cache from the backend.

Comment: Its so easy.Thumbs up

Comment: Cheers!! @Anees...

Comment: It works if you are using one store view only if you use multiple languages it will cause issue.